# Calling Control-M from Fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, control-m

Need to get help regarding calling Control-M from Fitnesse. Can I use ctmorder for that? I am able to execute .sh, .com and db scripts which are straight forward. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tools from Control-M for that (ctmorder, ctmpsm, ...).

Google for "Control-M utility_guide.pdf".

If you use the command line tools you would like to probably call them remote via SSH with a library like https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj or http://www.jcraft.com/jsch (we use sshj).

There is also a Java API and a Web Service API, as part of "business process integration". See https://communities.bmc.com/message/482038#482038 and https://communities.bmc.com/community/bmcdn/enterprise_scheduling_workload_automation/blog/2013/11/25/my-control-m-tech-tips-volume-1 for more information.